# How to add an image filter on top of an image?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to put a filter on top of my image but I just can't seem to get it right.

This is what I am trying to recreate:

[image: overlay-image]

You can see the red overlay on top of the image but it's also got like a darker tint to it.

I tried putting a relative div on top of the image and giving this a red background. After that I gave it an opacity and moved it around to see what looks the best. But it doesn't come anywhere near as you can see in this image
[image: My try]

I'm not sure where to look and I'm wondering whether this would even be possible with only html and css?

Comment: Isn't that just a problem of picking the proper color and adjust brightness? Seems like your div is at the same place.

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: @OldPadawan Unfortunately no, once you set the opacity lower and increaseing the brightness just makes it too washed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out to get the same result you need to set two CSS stylings.

First one being `mix-blend-mode: darken;`. Setting this to darken does actually almost all the work. It causes it to mix with the background images and text. But it becomes a little bit too dark, so to increase the contrast to add some more boom like in the result I want I added `filter: contrast(200%);`. These two together produces the following

[image: result]